# Bound of expectation of product

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

We know the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality,
\begin{align}
(E(XY))^2\le E(X^2)E(Y^2).
\end{align}
I am wodering whether the following holds for positive random variables $X$ and $Y$
\begin{align}
(E(X^mY^n))^2\le E(X^{m+n})E(Y^{m+n}).
\end{align}
This is just my guess, and the Cauchy–Schwarz inequality is special case of above with $m=n=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking $X=c$ and $Y$ following a standard lognormal distribution, it yields
$$c^{2m}\exp(m^2)=c^{2m}(\mathbb{E}[Y^n])^2\leq c^{m+n}\mathbb{E}[Y^{m+n}]=c^{m+n}\exp\bigl((m+n)^2/2\bigr).$$
That is,
$$c^{m-n}\leq\exp(n^{2}/2+mn-m^{2}/2)$$
should hold with any $c$. Note that RHS is fixed for any $m,n$, however, for any $m> n$, LHS can go to infinity as $c\to\infty$; and for any $m<n$, LHS can go to infinity as $c\to0$.
Therefore, it must be $m=n$. But in that case $$(\mathbb{E}[X^{n}Y^{n}])^{2}\leq \mathbb{E}[X^{2n}]\mathbb{E}[Y^{2n}]$$ is just a Cauchy–Schwarz inequality for $X^{n}$ and $Y^{n}$.

---

As pointed out by stochasticboy321, the issue of this inequality is
a lack of homogeneity when $m\neq n$: even if the relationship holds for $X,Y$, it cannot hold for $cX,Y$ either as $c\to0$ or as $c\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the right hand side of your first equation should be $E(Y^{m+n})$.

Comment: @Harry Sorry for the mistake. I've edited the answer, the procedure is different but the idea is the same, to show $m=n$.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is a nice arguement. Thus, the extension of Cauchy–Schwarz inequality does not hold in general.

Comment: Probably a good idea to point out that nothing is special about the particular $X,Y$ you've chosen - the issue is just a lack of homogeneity due to the differing degrees for each random variable, which means that even if the relationship holds for $X,Y$, it cannot hold for $cX,Y$ either as $c \to 0$ or as $c \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the comment!